# Symfony - Forms or AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, forms, symfony

I've 4 entities , the master entity is named "Jointure", others entities ( Skill.php , Level.php, Answer.php) are mapped ManyToOne to "Jointure". 
-Skill contains all possible skill choice.
-Level contains all possible level choice.
-Answer contains userEmail of each consultant.

i want to create a search page with criteria like that :
[image]

Simpler : i select a Skill(Compétence), then i select a Level(Maitrise) and then i click on "Recherche consultant" and i display a list with all "Answer.userEmail" that fill this.

How can i do that ? Forms with createQueryBuilder with custom Join ? EntityType ? with AJAX ?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Hey if I were you I would create a formType with 2 entity types for the search form and then use Ajax for the results.

SearchFormType.php :

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
    $builder->add(
            'skill',
            EntityType::class,
            [
                'class' => Skill::class,
            ]
         )
          ->add(
            'skillLevel',
            EntityType::class,
            [
                'class' => SkillLevel::class,
            ]
        );
    }
```

Then use jquery to intercept the submit and send it over Ajax instead:

app.js:

```
$('#form').on('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $form.serialize(),
        success: (response) => {
           //Display results in div       
        }
    })
})
```

And finally deal with the Ajax response in the controller

Controller.php :

```
public function search(Request $request){
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $search = $this->createForm(SearchFormType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $searchData = $form->getData();
            //Do what you want with the data and return a json response with the results
            return new JsonResponse([$results], 200);
        }
    } 
}
```

You will have to add the code that queries the database for the results and the error handling for this to be complete.

I might have missed something so if you try this approach and it doesn't work don't hesitate to leave a comment and I'll dig deeper.